# Jenkins not able to open a firefox window selenium (python )

Tags: python, firefox, selenium, jenkins

I'm able to run my Python code(`main.py`) perfectly alright.The problem  happens when I use `Jenkins` to run my Python code( `main.py`). `Jenkins` is not able to launch Firefox.

The line 
`driver = webdriver.Firefox()` is throwing an exception line this:

```
Entering main()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 21, in <module>
    driver = webdriver.Firefox()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/firefox/webdriver.py", line 59, in __init__
    self.binary, timeout),
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/firefox/extension_connection.py", line 47, in __init__
    self.binary.launch_browser(self.profile)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/firefox/firefox_binary.py", line 61, in launch_browser
    self._wait_until_connectable()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/firefox/firefox_binary.py", line 100, in _wait_until_connectable
    self._get_firefox_output())
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: "The browser appears to have exited before we could connect. The output was: \n(process:9287): GLib-CRITICAL **: g_slice_set_config: assertion `sys_page_size == 0' failed\nError: no display specified\n" 
Finished: SUCCESS


#############  Code snippet ###########

if __name__ ==  __main__  :

     driver = webdriver.Firefox()
     driver.implicitly_wait(10)
     driver.get("www.google.com")
```

Comment: You need to specify the display number. Or you do not use firefox but phantomjs. Have a look at both possibilities.

Answer (score 0):

Are you on windows platform and running Jenkins as a windows service?

If so then the remedy will be to run the Jenkins from the command line.